# trouble installing mono 6.12 release on Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: mono

I am in this mess because I followed Ubuntu 20.04 instructions here: https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/#download-lin-ubuntu  - those were supposed to work on my 21.10 too :)

That repository for stable-focal is horribly outdated and incompatible with 21.10.

Please point me to a working repository/package.

Comment: Something for 20.04 will work for 21.10? I believe that's a misunderstanding.

Comment: The page says " the packages should work on newer Ubuntu versions too but we only test the ones listed below."  
Apparently - this is not true..